# 301 permanent redirection to remove a parametre

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My problem is really simple but I really can't find a solution (even if I am not new with .htaccess configuration)

this is what I tried

```
#ENGLISH CORRECTION
RedirectMatch 301 ^en/(.*)/?$ $1
```

I have a multilingual website accessible from https://www.domain.com/<language>/<page>

I would like to have the <language> parameter only for languages different than english.. so what I would like to have is that

```
if <language> == en
301 redirect from /en/<page> to /<page>
```

Any idea on how to implement the system above ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but with mod_alias (the `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` directives), you need to match the leading slash:

```
#ENGLISH CORRECTION
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/(.*)/?$ $1
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. I tried your code but nothing happens.